# How to access c.str() content?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm working on an application that uses C++. I'm trying to access the content of this expression:

```
((std::string*) pPin->GetUserData())->c_str();
```

The problem is that I'm trying to pass this value to Java, through JNI, but in Java, this gets a new value, that has nothing to do with its original value, that I normally can see by using this: `EXAMPLE_LOG("User Data='%s'", ((std::string*) pPin->GetUserData())->c_str());`

I'd like to know how can I get this same value of log and send it to Java.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're pretending a pointer to a character is a pointer to a `std::string` and telling the compiler you know what you're doing. That isn't going going to end well.

Comment: What would you suggest, @chris? The value that I want is in pPin->GetUserData() that is a const void* object, but I'm having difficult to access it as well.

Comment: To send const char* to java you have to put it into jstring, JNI will make a copy of your data so in Java code you will see a copy. Whats wrong with that? You want to see a C++ pointer contents in Java code?

Comment: @AmandaBrito, Oh, my bad, sorry. I missed the closing bracket in the middle. Anyway, a `jstring` is what you need. You can make one from the `const char *` acquired from `c_str()`.

Comment: Won't this give me an exception anyway? Because of the types ... Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a string for java(jstring) from an existing char * or std::string, you use `NewStringUTF`

```
JNIEnv * env;
jclass loadedJavaClass;
jmethodID loadedJavaMethod;

//assume JVM, class, and method are already loaded at this point.

//Get c string from std::string object pointer
const char * c_string = ((std::string*) pPin->GetUserData())->c_str();

//Create jstring from string
jstring stuff = env->NewStringUTF( c_string );

//pass jstring to Java function
env->CallStaticVoidMethod( loadedJavaClass, loadedJavaMethod, stuff );

//remove local reference to jstring
JavaEnvironment::getEnvironment()->DeleteLocalRef(stuff);
```

Comment: When dealing with character data, you have to know the character set and encoding, either explicitly or knowing it is the default. It is unlikely that the data is in the _modified UTF-8_ encoding that `NewStringUTF` assumes. Many encodings are identical for a subset of characters so it _could_ work _sometimes._ The best way is to use a `java.lang.String` constructor using the known information about the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem, I really didn't know about this NewStringUTF function. I guess that the problem was really the encoding.